# Gmail: Forward any email addressed to a specific email, and any variations using the + operator to a different address, automatically?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I would like to set up forwarding behaviour in Gmail to forward any and all variations on an email address to a different email address.

So if I send an email to example@abc.com, example+test@abc.com, example+exe@abc.com etc., all would forward to a second email address without having to set up each one individually.

NOTE: In Gmail adding a "+" operator to the 'username' of the email address will send to that address as if the "+" operator and anything after it but before the @ symbol were not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways, depending on if the example@abc.com address has its own account.

**With Gmail Account (Licensed User)**

1. Login to the Gmail Account, click Settings icon and then "See all settings".
2. Go to "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab.
3. Click "Add a forwarding address" button in Forwarding section
4. Enter the desired address
5. Follow steps to verify address
6. Return to Forwarding tab, choose the option "Forward a copy of incoming mail to" and select the desired forwarding address and inbox action.
7. Scroll to bottom of page and select "Save Changes"
8. Forwarding for this inbox and all sub-addresses is now enabled!

**Without Account License, using Admin Console**

1. Go to Apps > Google Workspace/G Suite > Gmail
2. Open "Default routing" section
3. Add a Rule
4. Choose "Pattern match"
5. Copy in the following string: **example(+.*)?@abc.com**
6. Replace **example** for the address and **abc.com** for your domain
7. Check "Add X-Gm-Original-To header" and add "Add more recipients"
8. Add the desired forwarding address(es) under Add more recipients
9. Select "Perform this action on non-recognized and recognized addresses"
10. Click Save
11. Forwarding for this address and all sub-addresses is now enabled!